# A story about Mars, authorities/new colonists("gringoes") vs "local"/old colonists(humans), and a search for a native aliens base/hideout

Tags: story-identification, aliens, space-colonization

What I remember so far:

1. Medium-sized novel
2. Probably written before 90s (at least not later than 1998)
3. Male? author
4. All events happen on Mars (though it may be Venus or even something else)
5. There are two groups of humans:

   - government/military/newly arriving colonists
   - already present colonists/guerillas fighting(or at least actively hindering activities of) the first group, whom they call [gringoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gringo) or something similarly disparaging
6. For some reason, despite their mutual animosity, both groups have to cooperate (probably against some third power)
7. In the end they find (and probably destroy/disable) alien(native Martian?) base.
8. While investigating the base they find strangely looking/operating alien handheld weapons (one is basically a freeze gun, another shoots shards/lattices of something)

Comment: The first 5 points mostly match Pournelle's *Birth of Fire* which had a late 80s reprinting, bit the last points don't fit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've managed to remember the author - [Sterling E. Lanier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sterling_E._Lanier)

And the book is [Menace Under Marswood](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1366970.Menace_Under_Marswood) (1983)

> Mars in the 23rd century has been terraformed, and is being settled by Earth colonists. The outcast "Ruckers"---former settlers who have revolted--are oppsing this immigration.

> Marswood is set in a near future where Earth has colonized Mars and the United Nations is serving as the Solar System’s supra-government. Slater is a UN peace forces soldier who gets assigned on a secret mission deep into the Martian wilderness, in a combination manhunt for a dangerous criminal mastermind and investigation into hints that Earthmen may not be alone on Mars.

Comment: I like this book - I also recommend 'Hiero's Journey' by Lanier :)

Comment: I thought *Hiero's Journey* a bit silly.

Comment: Great book. Still waiting for a sequel.